# what is the command on resuming from suspend that activates the usb mouse/keyboard hub

Tags: usb, suspend

I often have problems with the USB hubs not working... I wont go into all that here.
but I have been able to get it to work by pressing the laptops power button and, even though it does not go into suspend and resumes straight away, it has been activating the previously inactive mouse and keyboard.
so what is the command  that ubuntu did to get this to work?

Comment: A lot of device drivers (in both linux and windows) do not wake up correctly after sleep.

Comment: my issues with ubuntu and this AMD Ryzen laptop over the last 3 years are far and wise and deep. I use several USB adapters and all have the same issue. Only today was I able to 'jack' the ethernet to connect unplugging and replugging the USB type C adapter in and out, twice.. that and random lockups are improving recently. so in short, it is not just one device.

Comment: It's probably not the device, but the usb chipset in your system.

Comment: yeh but I just got another one, same ryzen 5 but higher spec. and the battery life is 'Windows' 7hrs vs less than half that (with new battery same specs) . unless it is the PCIe NVMe  M.2  vs SSD and IDE drives.  ... who knows. suspend is problematic with this one too. no point complaining.

Comment: having hell with it for 4 years almost with HP envy ryzen 5 laptops, and happy with this ASUS TUF ryzen 5 laptop I had a non responsive mouse and keyboard this morning. rather than reboot I somehow pressed the function+display blank (f6) button, it went into the logout screen and,  after logging in, resumed ok. I think the wayland might have rebooted.. I have not repeated it but will keep an eye out for it as a solution, for me at least. I was pleasantly surprised it worked . maybe it was just timing (why would any keys work when alt-tab or power key did not I do not know)